# Refresh a Power Query with visible Queries and Connections Bar

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, screenupdating

I'm trying to refresh a query in a different Excel-file.

```vb
If Sheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 20) = True Then
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsm")
    wb1.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wb1.Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = True
    wb1.Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Width = 300
    wb1.Sheets("table1").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    wb1.Save
    wb1.Close
End If
```

The code works as intended and updates the query and saves it correctly before closing the file.

I want to see the Queries and Connections Bar. If I step through the code everything works. If I run the whole code at once the query works but it does not show the Connections Bar. `Application.Screenupdating=True` does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Just setting the `.Width` doesn't seem to be enough. You can force it to draw the CommandBar by resetting `.Position` though.

```
If Sheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 20) = True Then
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsm")
        With wb1
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            With .Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections")
                .Visible = True
                .Position = .Position
                .Width = 300
            End With
            .Sheets("table1").ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .Save
            .Close
        End With
End If
```

Comment: Hey and thank you for your response. But it's still not working. If I place a breakingpoint after the Refresh it shows the CommandBar right after the query has finished.

Comment: Weird, it works for me (different query, obviously). Maybe try putting a `DoEvents` line just before the refresh?